# Why doesn't Count work in my oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I am trying to do a count of items related to a person for my query, but I keep getting a

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Here is my query:

```
    select distinct
    p.person_id as id,
    p.fullname as name, 
    p.email, 
    (select count(*) from ASSETS_MASTER m, PERSON p where m.asset_user = p.person_id) as Assets,
    p.last_updated
 from person p 
where p.deleted = 0
order by p.fullname asc;
```

the error is because of :

```
select count(*) from ASSETS_MASTER m, PERSON p where m.asset_user = p.person_id
```

in which case :

asset_user is datatype varchar2(255)

person_id is datatype number

but if I run

```
select asset_id from ASSETS_MASTER m, PERSON p where m.asset_user = p.person_id
```

this will show results of

```
CFRI1823m
5384w
CFRI5039
CFRI2319
CFRI5024
....
```

Can anyone tell me what I am getting this error?

Comment: We can't tell without seeing your data. Are you perhaps trying to compare a string (`m.asset_user`) with a number (`p.person_id`), or something of that nature?

Comment: Even if `m.asset_user` is a string and `p.person_id` is a number, wouldn't Oracle do an implicit type conversion, or at the very least return the Cartesian product because that condition is never met?

Comment: @SandPiper - no, and no. If you try to compare a string to a number, Oracle will try to convert the string to a number, not the other way around (don't ask me why! - I would rather Oracle threw an error and didn't attempt anything behind my back). And if the string can't be converted you get exactly that error. And then: it would return the empty set; it would be the Cartesian product if the condition is always true. But that condition (with VARCHAR2 compared to NUMBER) is never true and it is never false; rather, it is syntactically incorrect and Oracle should reject it for data type mismatch

Comment: @SandPiper so asset_user is varchar and person_id is number, but if i remove the count(*) and change it to id (for example), there query runs normally

Comment: @charlietsai - what do you mean by "the query runs normally"? I don't believe that. It would help if you can show the exact query you are running - to the original post, not in comments.

Comment: And the better question is, why are you attempting to join on a condition that can't possibly be correct? Is ASSET_USER actually supposed to be a number (to match PERSON_ID in the other table)? If so, then the tables should be fixed first; you should never have to join tables on a pair of columns that aren't even the same data type.

Comment: @SandPiper I edited the question to a more complete explanation I think...Hope this can help you to answer my question

Comment: Have you tried modifying that line like one of the three answers has suggested yet? What was the result of that?

Answer (score 0):

To further illustrate the point I made in a Comment, which was:

> We can't tell without seeing your data. Are you perhaps trying to
>   compare a string (`m.asset_user`) with a number (`p.person_id`), or
>   something of that nature?

Here is a similar example using the EMPLOYEES and DEPARTMENTS tables in the standard HR schema (which exists by default, after installation, on most Oracle systems):

```
select count(*) from hr.employees e, hr.departments d 
                where e.department_id = d.department_name;

ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathguy has an interesting explanation in the comments above. I don't know why you have your asset_user as VARCHAR if it is a number, and you might want to consider modifying the data type if you can. However, if it is possible to type convert to a number (i.e. your asset_user doesn't have values like `AD34`), you should be able to fix your query by doing this:

```
select count(*) from ASSETS_MASTER m, PERSON p 
where CAST(m.asset_user AS INT) = p.person_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select count(*) from ASSETS_MASTER m, PERSON p where m.asset_user = '' || p.person_id
```

but it will prevent the use of the index of p.person_id
in this case you'll have to create a functional index of to_char(person_id)

Answering your question directly - in your query Oracle implicitly calls to_number for varchar m.asset_user. It works fine until m.asset_user is assigned to something like '12345' or null or even ''... but once it meets something like '1 23' - it returns invalid number.